# How to pass dynamic variable starting with special character as an argument in bash/shell script

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters

I'm trying to call one script from jenkins pipeline where I'm passing dynamic variable as an argument as shown below.
dbpassword variable contains value as #!2323qwq i.e. starting from special characters. I'm executing this script within double quotes and if I use single quotes within double quotes, will it expand my variable and pass it successfully ?

```
sh "./script-test.sh $dbpassword"
```

where as script-test.sh script contains below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_pwd=$1
echo "password: $new_pwd"
sqlplus username/$new_pwd
```

But, It shows blank in the output command:

```
password:
```

Could you please let us know how can I pass the variable which contains special character? So that I can use that as password for sqlplus command in the script.

Comment: Always quote your variables.

Comment: @Barmar - If I use single quotes , will it expand my variable ? I'm already calling the shell script in the double quotes. Please clarify this.

Comment: The argument to `sh` is a filename, not a command line. Did you mean `sh -c`? Also, `sh` is not the same as `bash`.

Comment: `bash -c "./script-test.sh '$dbpassword'"`. Then in the script you need `sqlplus "username/$new_pwd"`

Comment: Avoid using `sh -c` if at all possible -- it adds an extra level of parsing, which makes quoting/escaping exponentially more complex and messy.